# How do I group by month and year when only having a datetime field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table schema which is essentially a bunch of transaction info with a datetime field

```
TRANSACTION (< transactionid >, amount, when)
```

I need to generate a monthly total of transactions, which is SUM(amount), but I stumped by what do I group by. Each row from SQL should contain the monthly total (so one row for Jan 09, Feb 09....Jan 2010 and so on). I am thinking that I may have to generate the table by code, but would like to learn if there is a way to resolve this using SQL.

Any help would be appreciated! (Using MySQL 5.3, PHP5)

Comment: just notice for newbie, `when` is the table column name not an MySQL function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to group by extracts.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount)
FROM 
    transaction
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM when),
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM when)
```

And if you need those columns, then

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM when) as month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM when) as year, 
    SUM(amount)
FROM 
    transaction
GROUP BY 
    month,
    year
```

Of course you can append `ORDER BY` and use short names too:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM when) as month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM when) as year, 
    SUM(amount)
FROM 
    transaction
GROUP BY 
    month, 
    year
ORDER BY 
    year DESC, 
    month DESC
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM when), sum(amount)
      FROM TRANSACTION
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM when)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've always used MONTH() and YEAR()...which seems a little bit like a Hack to me, but it works...

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM yourTable GROUP BY MONTH(date), YEAR(date)
```

Or was it the other way round? *thinks*

Bobby

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like that:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(when) AS year,
  MONTH(when) AS month,
  SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM
  TRANSACTION
GROUP BY
  YEAR(when),
  MONTH(when)
ORDER BY
  YEAR(when),
  MONTH(when)
```

This works on MS SQL and should work on MySQL too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(date), '-', MONTH(date))
```