# Query: Show the name of the salesmen with more that 4 invoices in the same month

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Query in PostgreSQL: Show the name of the salesmen with more than 4 invoices in the same month.

tables: `articles, customers, invoices, lines_invoice, province, towns, sellers`.

my query returns values without taking care of the count being in the same month, how can I do that?

```
select s.codseller, s.name 
from sellers s 
join invoices i using (codseller) 
group by s.codseller 
having count (codinvoice) > 4;
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

The correct solution showed on screen is:
 [image: Result]

codven = codseller
nombre = name

With my query it shows two extra rows, because it counts  salesmen with more than 4 invoices but in different months.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
      ,date_trunc('month', i.sales_date::timestamp) AS month
      ,COUNT(i.id) AS invoices_for_month
  FROM seller s
  INNER JOIN invoices i ON (s.id = i.seller_id)
  GROUP BY s.id, s.name, date_trunc('month', i.sales_date::timestamp)
  HAVING COUNT(i.id) > 4
```

The environment tested on:

```
CREATE TABLE seller (id int, name text);
INSERT INTO seller VALUES(1, 'Joe');
INSERT INTO seller VALUES(2, 'Mike');
INSERT INTO seller VALUES(3, 'Tom');

CREATE TABLE invoices(id int, seller_id int, sales_date date);
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES(1, 1, now());
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES(2, 1, now() - interval '35' day);
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES(3, 1, now() - interval '37' day);
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES(4, 1, now() - interval '39' day);
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES(5, 1, now() - interval '40' day);
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES(6, 1, now() - interval '40' day);
INSERT INTO invoices VALUES(7, 2, now());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave the answer here but Glenn's answer is better

You have to extract the month in your group_by clause (untested):

```
select s.codseller, 
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM i.date) as month, 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM i.date) as year, s.name 
from sellers s 
join invoices i using (codseller) 
group by s.codseller, month, year
having count (codinvoice) > 4;
```

Please also have a look at [How do I group by month and year when only having a datetime field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559201/how-do-i-group-by-month-and-year-when-only-having-a-datetime-field)

You should also have a look at postgresqls [datetime functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: I think it is easier than that, see my edit of my question ;-)

Comment: @ÁngelCarlosdelPozoMuela i don't understand your edit as you don't show the query but you have to either truncate the date or extract the month

Comment: The table of the solution is given by my teacher, so I don't know the query he uses. My query, which it's shown in my question, gets 10 results, and my teacher's one 8. That's because two of my results consider more than four invoices, but in different months.