# Average of summed variables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, average

I have a query for a MYSQL database which is as follows:

```
SELECT name,
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Dec, 2011', 1,0)) AS `month1`, 
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jan, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month2`, 
SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Feb, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month3`, 
etc...
COUNT(*) AS total FROM table order by total
```

However instead of a total I need an average of month1 to month12.

EDIT - I need to retain the SUMMED numbers (month1,2 etc) but I ALSO need an average of them all to be calculated.

So, if the results for month1-12 were -

55, 60, 70, 54, 89, 58, 68, 78, 65, 89, 73, 81
and the TOTAL is 840

I need to calculate the average of all those figures (70)

Thanks

Comment: USE AVG function instead of SUM function

Comment: `AVG` of what; and do you need an average by month?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasnt clear.  The SUM of Month1 will bring me a result say 100, the SUM of Month2, 300 etc etc.  I need the average of all these SUMs - ie average of (Month1, Month2, Month3 - 12)

Comment: I suggest rewriting your query to look more like the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559201/how-do-i-group-by-month-and-year-when-only-having-a-datetime-field

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,
AVG(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Dec, 2011', 1,0)) AS `month1`, 
AVG(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jan, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month2`, 
AVG(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Feb, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month3`, 
-- etc...
COUNT(*) AS total FROM table order by total
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
SELECT name,
AVG(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Dec, 2011', 1,0)) AS `month1`, 
AVG(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Jan, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month2`, 
AVG(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Feb, 2012', 1,0)) AS `month3`, 
etc...
COUNT(*) AS total FROM table order by total
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasnt clear.  The SUM of Month1 will bring me a result say 100, the SUM of Month2, 300 etc etc.  I need the average of all these SUMs - ie average of (Month1, Month2, Month3 - 12)